# Kinect V2: instantaneous scan but then it stops scanning (Kinectfusion)

Tags: 3d, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox, kinect-interaction, kinect-v2

IM using kinectfusion explorer d2d and when I use it it scans right away, but then it stops scanning? Is it the settings? what should I put to set it right?

some one answered :"If I'm not mistaken, the Kinect scanner has a fairly low maximum polygon limit. Maybe you're running out and it's stalling?"

HOW CAN I RAISE THE POLYGON COUNT LIMIT?